# Different results in production vs evaluation - Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, regression

I have built a cryptocurrency regression model but it performs different in real-life then the evaluation over the same period.

I am using exchange **binance**. In production I call my custom the predict() function each 15min just after the new data sample has closed. Since data is real-time I use the sample at index `-2` because `-1` is real-time and will still change. I also specify the timestamp of the sample I want in the predict() function so there are no mismatches.

I ran the program from 05-02-22 (DD-MM-YY) till 09-02-22 but when I evaluate over the same period it shows very different results: (BTW the model is not trained over this period)

```
Real Life:
 * profits: -7.5
 * precision: 0.40
 * trades: 10

Evaluation over the same period:
 * profits: 5.32
 * precision: 0.72
 * trades: 25
```

So I tested if there was an error in the prediction code. When I call my custom predict() function for each timestamp `[05-02-22 00:00, 05-02-22 15:00, 05-02-22 30:00, ..., 09-02-22 XX:XX]` and then evaluate the results. It is exactly the same as the evaluation results. Therefore I conclude there is no error in the predict() function which causes this.

**Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?**

The custom predict function (Don't know if it helps).

```
# predict symbols.
def predict(self,
    # single symbol to predict.
    symbol=None,
    # the symbols to predict.
    symbols=[],
    # the expected timestamp.
    timestamp=None,
    # hide the errors.
    hide_errors=False,
    # use multiprocessing.
    multiprocessing=False,
    # max processes.
    max_processes=15,
):

    # by single.
    if symbol != None:

        # fetch df <-- Same function used in training & evaluation.
        X, Y = self.fetch_symbol(symbol=symbol, lookup=False, mode="live")

        # check empty dataframe.
        if len(Y) == 0:
            raise exceptions.EmptyDataFrame(f"{symbol} - Encoutered an empty dataframe.")

        # slice df.
        if timestamp == None:
            X = X[len(X)-1:len(X)]
            Y = Y[len(Y)-1:len(Y)]
        else:
            timestamp = int(Date(timestamp).to_seconds())
            for index in [-1, -2]:
                if int(Y.iloc[index]["timestamp"]/1000) == timestamp:
                    X = X[len(X)+index:len(X)+index+1]
                    Y = Y[len(Y)+index:len(Y)+index+1]
                    break
            if len(Y) != 1:
                if not hide_errors:
                    logging.log(f"&RED&Error&END&: Unable to find timestamp '{Date(timestamp)}' in the {symbol} dataframe.")

        # predict.
        timestamp = Date(Y.iloc[0]["timestamp"]/1000)
        if multiprocessing:
            return [[symbol, timestamp, X]]
        prediction = float(self.model.model.predict(X)[0][0])
        return [{
            "timestamp":timestamp,
            "symbol":symbol,
            "prediction":prediction,
            #"lookup":Y.iloc[index]["lookup"],
        }]

    # by multiple.
    else:

        # single process.
        if not multiprocessing:
            loader = ProgressLoader(f"Predicting {len(symbols)} symbols.", max=len(symbols), calc_finish=True, log_duration=True)
            possibilities = []
            for symbol in symbols:
                try:
                    possibilities += self.predict(symbol=symbol, timestamp=timestamp)
                except exceptions.InvalidDataFrame as e:
                    if not hide_errors:
                        logging.log(f"&RED&Error&END&: {e}")
                except exceptions.EmptyDataFrame as e:
                    if not hide_errors:
                        logging.log(f"&RED&Error&END&: {e}")
                except exceptions.InternalServerError as e:
                    if not hide_errors:
                        logging.log(f"&RED&Error&END&: {e}")
                loader.next()
            loader.stop()
            return possibilities

        # multiprocessing.
        else:

            # fetch data.
            def fetch(symbols=[], timestamp=None, hide_errors=False, id=0, memory={}):
                data = []
                for symbol in symbols:
                    try:
                        data += self.predict(symbol=symbol, timestamp=timestamp, hide_errors=hide_errors, multiprocessing=True)
                    except exceptions.InvalidDataFrame as e:
                        if not hide_errors:
                            logging.log(f"&RED&Error&END&: {e}")
                    except exceptions.EmptyDataFrame as e:
                        if not hide_errors:
                            logging.log(f"&RED&Error&END&: {e}")
                    except exceptions.InternalServerError as e:
                        if not hide_errors:
                            logging.log(f"&RED&Error&END&: {e}")
                    except Exception as e:
                        if not hide_errors:
                            logging.log(f"&RED&Unknown Error&END&: {e}")
                memory[id] = data

            # start processes.
            if max_processes > len(symbols):
                max_processes = len(symbols)
            processes = []
            mp_manager = __multiprocessing__.Manager()
            memory = mp_manager.dict({})
            divided = Array(symbols).divide(into=max_processes)
            for id in range(max_processes):
                p = __multiprocessing__.Process(target=fetch, args=(divided[id], timestamp, hide_errors, id, memory))
                p.start()
                processes.append(p)
            for p in processes:
                p.join()
                p.close()
            data = []
            for id in range(max_processes):
                try:
                    data += memory[id]
                except KeyError:
                    logging.log(f"&RED&Error&END&: Failed to retrieve data from process {id}.")
            
            # predict on data.
            possibilities = []
            for symbol, timestamp, X in data:
                prediction = float(self.model.model.predict(X)[0][0])
                possibilities += [{
                    "timestamp":timestamp,
                    "symbol":symbol,
                    "prediction":prediction,
                }]
            return possibilities
```

And how i call the function:

```
neuralnet.predict(symbols=neuralnet.symbols, multiprocessing=True, timestamp=str(Date(timestamp)))
```

I already contacted binance support and they say that once the data is released the data will never change again. So this should also not be the problem.

This is all the code used in prediction an processing the predictions https://github.com/vandenberghinc/issue-1. If you read the code you can see that some valid predictions are limited for example if there are multiple possibilites it selects the one where the highest price change is predicted. But without all this limitations it would have made only 13 trades instead of 10. I checked the logs, so that should not be the problem.

**Any help would be very much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Have you compared the data that you are using in your custom `predict` function with the data you are using when evaluating the model? In addition, what do you mean with "when I call my custom predict() function for each timestamp" and how does this method differ from when you are getting different results?

Comment: @Oxbowerce - Well the normal evaluation function uses the data from 05-02-22 (DD-MM-YY) till 09-02-22 and makes predictions on the entire X from this period, then evaluates it. I tested the predict function by just calling the predict() result for each timestamp in that period separately and then made the eval.